# Column headers are dynamically increased with Rows in Sub report of Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

[image] This image shows you that report has been created with 2 rows with repeated with its column headers along with it. Its getting increased when the no of rows increased. let me know the solution fix this. i've used subreport for this.

same problem exists without using the subreport. but the pages are getting increased with the no of rows. ex. if the now of rows are 3 then generated pages will be 9. kindly let us the know the solution to get rid off this problem. Rows are dynamically getting increased with header values. we have implement a subreport in detail band. we had a column headers in column header & dynamic rows in detail band of sub report.

Answer (score 0):

The **detail band of report will execute for the number of times equivalent to the number of rows fetched from the DB on firing the query of the main report.** As such your sub report which is kept inside the detail band of main report is not necessarily a good report design strategy. 
**Try putting the subreport in the summary band or place it inside a group.****

Since your detail band will be called everytime, the sub report will be executed everytime the detailed band is everytime. This will keep on adding the entry inside the sub report and will print the sub report again in the next iteration of the main report detail band.